# org-mode: Possible to save Agenda Global TODO list order?

Tags: org-mode

I'm new to org-mode and wondering if after editing the order of items in the Global TODO List, if you can save that preferred order.

I've tried C-x C-s but that doesn't seem to do anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could manually change the order of items in the agenda.  How are you doing that?  (I think `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` is the variable you should have a look at.)

Comment: Using C-c a t, you can then use M-up/down arrows to move todo list items around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible to save this.  The footnote for
`org-agenda-drag-line-forward` in the manual
(`(info "(org) Agenda commands")`) says

```
(2) Moving agenda lines does not persist after an agenda refresh and
does not modify the contributing ‘.org’ files
```

The command doesn't save any information to make this persist.  I
think reordering the original Org file and setting
`org-agenda-sorting-strategy` is the only way to get sorting changes to persist across agenda calls.